# Prevent hyperlink auto-creation

Tags: html, google-chrome

I notice the Chrome browser automatically creates hyperlinks for web address references that are not anchor tags.  I have a page which will list web addresses (e.g.: **www.mycompany.com**).  But in this instance having them converted to links makes things more confusing.

Is there an html tag I can use to prevent this?

Comment: can you share a bit of HTML code?

Comment: Do you have something like this installed?: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mblbciejcodpealifnhfjbdlkedplodp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just create a file that I called test.html with the following content:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>
www.microsoft.com
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I opened it in Google Chrome.

The text is not hyper-linked. 
There might be something else going on you are not describing. Can you give an html that can reproduce your problem?

It can be settings related or you might have some javascript on your page that "linkifying" whatever looks like a url. Or a browser plugin.

Comment: Yeah - I should have added it was contained in a html based email (should have thought like you and did the html straight in a browser).    Both in Godaddy Web Mail and Yahoo Mail it is showing up as a link.  So these email clients must be "linkifying" them.  But is there a way of telling them with tags not to do this?